# getX null initial value and use '??' but getting The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have get value of `RxString? name;` and want to use in the `Text()` widget like

```
Text(uController.name() ?? 'noooo nameeee'),
```

However, it causes an error of

> The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be
> 'null'. Try adding a null check ('!').

Even if I add `?` to RxString, I can't use it as null assignable. Is there any way that I can use GetX with `??` command?

```
// my GetxController file
class uController extends GetxController {
  RxString? name;
}

uController uController = Get.find();
```

I'd just tried with `(_uController?.name() ?? 'noooo nameeee')`, I still get

> The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be
> 'null'. Try adding a null check ('!').

```
uController _uController = Get.put(uController());

class DashboardView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Obx(() => Column(
                children: [
                  Text(_uController.name() ?? 'hmm'),
                  Text(_uController?.name() ?? 'hmm'),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    )); .....
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both `?.` and `??`

```
Text(uController?.name() ?? 'noooo nameeee'),
```

For more read this https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: I get the same error + `The receiver can't be null, so the null-aware operator '?.' is unnecessary.` on `?.` :/

Comment: Please share uController.name() part code, it would helpful to debug

Comment: Sorry mate, I just added the code and screenshot

Comment: `_uController.name.value` try with please

Comment: Sir, you saved me 3 days + 10 RedBull + 100 Google search. thank you so much!